Is there a limit of writing to the NV space of TPM 2.0 using c#?
Been trying to write and read my own keys from the TPM (AES 256) using c# with .NET 4.8
After starting to test my code i noticed that defining space after multiple (specifically 5) successful writes in a NvSpace exception.
I would like to know if there's any known limit to the user writing on the TPM.
relevent code (assuming i have a handler representing a free space)
public static void LoadKeyToTPM(byte[] key, uint nvIndexHandle)
 {
    Tpm2Device tpmDevice = new TbsDevice();
    tpmDevice.Connect();
    // Create a TPM context
    Tpm2 tpm = new Tpm2(tpmDevice);
    // Check if an available NV space handle was found
    if (nvIndexHandle != 0)
    {
        // Define NV public area with the necessary attributes
        NvPublic nvPublic = new NvPublic(
        new TpmHandle(nvIndexHandle),       // NV Index handle
        TpmAlgId.Sha256,                    // Name algorithm
        NvAttr.Authwrite | NvAttr.Authread, // NV attributes
        ComputeHMAC(secretKey),             // Authorization policy
        512                                 // Data size
        );

        TpmHandle ownerAuth = new TpmHandle(TpmRh.Owner);

        // Define the NV space, crushes here after 5 successful attemps
        tpm.NvDefineSpace(ownerAuth, ComputeHMAC(secretKey), nvPublic);
                
        // Write data to NV memory
        WriteNV(tpm, nvIndexHandle, key, secretKey);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No available NV space found.");
    }
}

Solutions i've tried:

Write on different parts of the NV space (not consecutive slots)
Write in different sessions to see if there's some time gating
Write the same key over and over and even a random string just to verify the problem isnt the data being written.
Define more space than needed on each define attemp
Checking the manufacturer for some types of limitations on space or slot consumption


See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/hardware-security/tpm/initialize-and-configure-ownership-of-the-tpm

Figured out the problem - my organization limited the allocation slots using the TPM logically, so it showed having much more slots and after specifically 5 nv allocations started failing. tested on another machine and working properly.
